# Format date dd/mm/yyyy keeping Date type TypeORM

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

I need to insert the dates in dd/mm/yyyy format to match the other technologies in my application. I am using Nestjs, TypeOrm and Postgresql as database.

I tried to use the @Transform decorator like in the documentation

```
  @Transform(({ value }) => moment(value).format('DD/MM/YYYY'))
  @Column()
  encoded_date: Date;
```

Except that it always inserts a timestamp and returns a timestamp.
Is it possible to have a similar behavior to_date('25/02/2023', 'DD/MM/YYYY')::date, as one does in an sql script ? And Keeping Date type ?

---

I also tried this and that's give me yyyy-mm-dd but no way to format
like dd/mm/yyyy

```
 @CreateDateColumn({type:'date'})
  encoded_date: Date;
```

Comment: Columns defined with the data type `date` do not have any format. You need to format the value when _displaying_ it.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Can I give it a format ? With my python script I can insert and have dd/mm/yyyy format in my DB but I can not do the same with TypeOrm.

Comment: On db-end, you can alter your [`datestyle`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-DATESTYLE) setting to modify default input text-to-date and output date-to-text formats (see also [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/19679/how-to-set-postgresql-database-to-see-date-as-mdy-permanently)). Or as you said, use a [`to_date(your_date,'DD/MM/YYYY')` on input and `to_char(your_date,'DD/MM/YYYY')`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html#FUNCTIONS-FORMATTING-TABLE) on output.

Comment: 1) *Except that it always inserts a timestamp and returns a timestamp.* indicates the field the data is being stored in is actually a `timestamp(tz)` type not a `date` type. One way you could make things easier, assuming you want just date values, is to change the type to `date`. 2) As mentioned the `date` type does not store formatted dates, that is something you do at the presentation layer.

Answer (score 1):

On db-end, you can alter your [`datestyle`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-DATESTYLE) setting to modify default input text-to-date and output date-to-text formats (see also [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/19679/how-to-set-postgresql-database-to-see-date-as-mdy-permanently)). As with most settings:

- this can be set differently in [transaction, session, role, database, system contexts](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/config-setting.html#CONFIG-SETTING-SQL-COMMAND-INTERACTION), in that order of priority
- each session can override the setting, which some ORMs (can be configured to) do on connection init and each client can additionally issue a `SET` of its own
- the change won't affect other, ongoing sessions

You can also interface with your data through [formatting functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html#FUNCTIONS-FORMATTING-TABLE) in both directions, using:

- `to_date(your_date,'DD/MM/YYYY')` on input, which you mentioned
- `to_char(your_date,'DD/MM/YYYY')` on output.

[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/odiZDVNS)

```sql
show datestyle;
-- DateStyle
-------------
-- ISO, MDY
select 'today'::date;
--    date
--------------
-- 2023-03-24
select '03/24/2023'::date;
--ERROR:  date/time field value out of range: "03/24/2023"
--LINE 2: select '03/24/2023'::date;
--               ^
--HINT:  Perhaps you need a different "datestyle" setting.
select to_char(to_date('03/24/2023','MM/DD/YYYY'), 'MM/DD/YYYY');
--  to_char
--------------
-- 03/24/2023
set datestyle='SQL, MDY';
SET
select 'today'::date;
--    date
--------------
-- 03/24/2023
select '03/24/2023'::date;
--    date
--------------
-- 03/24/2023
```

As to the underlying format of the `date`/`time`/`timestamp`, with or without timezone: it's always just a number. Postgres uses the format mask given or implied by settings to calculate an epoch, then the timezone implied by settings or a supplied time zone name or offset, to shift it to internal UTC - and after that it doesn't keep them. These types are meant to hold a *when*. ***Where*** and ***how*** help pinpoint the exact, absolute ***when***, but they aren't its integral elements, so the source timezone and format it came in are discarded unless saved separately.

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom transfomer than converts input string to Date object.

```
@Column({
    type: 'date',
    transformer: {
      from: (value: string) => new Date(value),
      to: (value: Date) => value.toISOString().slice(0, 10), // format the Date to YYYY-MM-DD
    },
  })
  encoded_date: Date;
```

Comment: It doesn't work because it's the same code I have but with a different syntax.

Comment: Postgres seems to follow the same format no matter what when inserting in db for the Date object in typeorm.